# Incorrect cyrillic symbols representation in the GNU screen program

Tags: gnu-screen, charset

I use screen program to run a game server on a VDS. Sometimes I need to see what happens in the game and open SSH session via Putty and then run screen -x ... as usual. Recently I faced with weird behavior of the screen, it shows some particular letters as dotted rectangles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViqlD.png
I checked system locale:

```
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
ru_RU.utf8

localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```

I'm not sure is this ok or not. Anyway, if I open a log file of the game server I see that all the characters are shown correct. I mean it's only screen works weird... Also I tried to force the screen to use utf8 charset (:utf8 on) and it didn't help at all, I got quetion marks instead of cyrillic symbols. What to check / set up /change to fix this issue? Thanks!